# Finding words with and without whitespaces in Rails and Postgresql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out a statement I can use in Ruby on Rails that does a SQL query to match a word that might or might not have any whitespaces with a similar word that also might or might not have any whitespaces. 
For example:

> Matthew Jones
>   or
>   MatthewJones

should match

> Matthew Jones
>   or
>   MatthewJones

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using postgres [REPLACE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-string.html) function:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
    WHERE REPLACE(username, ' ', '') = REPLACE("Matthew Jones", ' ', '')
```

and it will match both `MatthewJones` and `Matthew Jones`.

You can write something like this in ActiveRecord query:

```
MyTable.where("REPLACE(username, ' ', '') = REPLACE('John Bob Jones', ' ', '')")
```

#### Update:

You can use `ILIKE` to make the query case-insensitive:

```
User.where("REPLACE(username, ' ', '') ILIKE REPLACE(?, ' ', '')", "John Bob Jones")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that Rakibul. I've replaced the "=" with "ILIKE" so that it is also case-insensitive:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE REPLACE(username, ' ', '') ILIKE REPLACE("Matthew Jones", ' ', '')
```

To do this using Active Record Query Interface in Ruby on Rails:

```
User.where("REPLACE(username, ' ', '') ILIKE REPLACE(?, ' ', '')", "Matthew Jones")
```

Comment: defenitely you can do that. 
If my answer helped you to solve your problem, please consider accepting/upvoting my answer. Thanks.